# How do I pass values between two tabs in a UITabBarController

Tags: tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I am stuck at one task where I am using a Tabbed Application where I have two tabs.

In one tab, I have one text field where I can enter my details and on click of a button I want to save that text field data and show that in the Second tab.

I used putting a variable as string in the controller for the second tab and assigning it with the text field value. It is getting assigned in the first view's controller but when I am trying to retrieve it in second tab's controller I am getting a null value.

Comment: Can you try to add some of your code?  It will be very difficult to help without knowing what you are doing and have tried.

Comment: You could post your code and what you've searched to solve your problem.